API Request containing image data for AWS Lambda
I am using an AWS Lambda function that receives images converted to base64 strings as inputs, splits images into smaller images (usually around 200), performs some calculations, and returns some numbers. I am using an HTTP API gateway triggered via the requests library in python. Input images are rather large, usually around 1-2 MB in TIF format.
I am facing an issue that for some of the larger images, when sending the request I am exceeding the payload limit and get "Request Entity Too Large".
The function that converts the image to strings looks as follows:
import base64
from io import BytesIO

def image_to_request_str(img):
    output = BytesIO()
    img.save(output, format="png")
    image_as_string = base64.b64encode(output.getvalue()).decode("ascii")
    return image_as_string

Sending the request looks like this:
import requests
import cv2
from PIL import Image

# Read image data
img = cv2.imread(path_to_image)

# Convert image
img_str = image_to_request_str(Image.fromarray(img))

# Send request
result = requests.post(api_address, json={name: img_str})

To avoid getting this issue, I tried to split up the images before sending the payload to AWS lambda, and instead of sending all of the smaller images at once (say 200 smaller images), sending them in two batches of 100 each using the same code as before, but adding more entries to the dictionary that I am sending through my request:
# Send request
result = requests.post(api_address, json={image_1: img_1_str, image_2: img_2_str, image_3: img_3_str, ...})

Funnily enough, I am getting the same error ("Request Entity Too Large") now for the individual batches - my approach of breaking down the images seems to increase the payload size drastically.
My questions:

Is there a more efficient way to send images through an API endpoint to a lambda function - potentially avoiding the payload limit in the first place.
Why is the payload size growing when splitting up the images into smaller ones, and how could this be avoided?

Any help would be much appreciated!

"I am also asking for a more effective way to send images in a request, which closely relates to its conversion from an array, potentially using cv2. So I wouldn't call the tag irrelevant." -- I would deal with that separately, questions should be focused (and you already have 2 questions in one post).

If you can't send the data you need to process in Lambda via the API endpoint, you so consider uploading it to S3 and sending a pointer to S3 from the Lambda to pull down the data.

I'm not sure I quite understand your request payload. You say a maximum size is 2MB. After encoding in base 64, that should be a maximum of 3MB. The lambda payload maximum is 6MB. Are you sending anything else with the request? You appear to be transcoding the image, is that increasing its size?
